# MQFTE Browse Remote Agent not enabled in MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I am trying file transfer between two windows servers connected over network in the same domain. I have successfully connected with remote agent through Explorer but when try to browse the destination directory in remote system I find it is not enabled. I do not see any specific error in agent logs.
I do not see any specific error in MQ or Agent logs as I am actually not able to do anything.
Is this because the user I use does not have write access in the remote server. If that is the case How can I make sure the user has write access in the remote server?. The user I use has write access on remote server on direct login. Please find attached screenshot.[image: Browse remote Agent disabled]

When I run in command mode I get 2087 reason code

```
C:\>fteCreateTransfer -sa AGENT1 -sm hubQM -da AGENT3 -dm hubQ
M -w -dd "D:\MQFTE\Destination" "D:\MQFTE\Source\sample.txt"
```

5724-H72 Copyright IBM Corp.  2008, 2012.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
BFGCL0003E: A messaging problem prevented the command from completing successful
ly, for queue SYSTEM.FTE.COMMAND.AGENT1 on queue manager hubQM. The WebSphere MQ
 completion code was 2, and the reason code was 2087.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `2087` means `MQRC_UNKNOWN_REMOTE_Q_MGR`.  This indicates that the QMgr that your WMQ Explorer is connected to cannot resolve the QMgr where the remote agent is connected.  You'll need to look at your FTE Command QMgr to make sure it has a path to the QMgr where the remote agent lives.